# How to capture the value from ComboBox in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, mvvm-light

I'm trying to capture the value of the selected item from a `ComboBox` in my ViewModel. I do get the value but for some reason, when I do a string comparison in an IF statement to determine which item has been selected the comparison doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Is this the right way to capture the value in ViewModel?

#### XAML

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemInFilter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}>

        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">No Selection</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Car</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Truck</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

#### ViewModel

```
    public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase{

            public string _selectedItemInFilter;
            public string SelectedItemInFilter
            {
                get { return _selectedItemInFilter; }
                set {
                    if (_selectedItemInFilter != value) {
                        _selectedItemInFilter = value;
                        ComboBoxChanged();
                        Console.WriteLine("SelectedItem: {0}", SelectedItemInFilter); // outputs the right item name
                        RaisePropertyChanged();
                    }
                }
            }

            private void ComboBoxChanged()
            {
                if (SelectedItemInFilter.ToString() == "Car") {
                    Console.WriteLine("Do something with car...");
                }
                else {
                    Console.WriteLine("Is not Car...");
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you explicitly add ComboBoxItems (instead of setting or binding the ItemsSource to a collection of strings), the SelectedItem also is a ComboBoxItem, and not a string. You may however bind to the `Content` string of the selected item by using `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath`:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItemInFilter}"
          SelectedValuePath="Content">
    <ComboBoxItem>No Selection</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Car</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Truck</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Even simpler would be not to use ComboBoxItems at all:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
...

<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemInFilter}">
    <sys:String>No Selection</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Car</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Truck</sys:String>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath are the key. And UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged on a SelectedItem or SelectedValue binding is redundant.

Comment: @Clemens: Thanks for the substantial improvement of the answer!

Comment: @fs_tigre In case you're missing the `IsSelected="True"` part, that wouldn't have worked correctly anyway. If you bind SelectedItem or SelectedValue, the view model should always provide the initial value. A workaround is a Loaded handler that sets SelectedIndex to zero.

Comment: @Clemens I'm not sure I understand your suggestion, I left the `<ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">No Selection</ComboBoxItem>` Are you suggesting to remove it and go with the workaround you are suggesting? If yes, how do I set up a Loader handler?

Comment: No workaround is needed when you initialize the SelectedItemInFilter property with "No Selection".

Answer (score 2):

You are getting it wrong because the items aren't really strings, if you need to do this way you could do the following:

```
public object _selectedItemInFilter;

    public object SelectedItemInFilter
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItemInFilter;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItemInFilter != value)
            {
                _selectedItemInFilter = value;
                ComboBoxChanged();
                Console.WriteLine("SelectedItem: {0}", SelectedItemInFilter); // outputs the right item name
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItemInFilter");
            }
        }
    }
    private void ComboBoxChanged()
    {
        if (((ComboBoxItem)SelectedItemInFilter).Content.ToString() == "Car")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do something with car...");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Is not Car...");
        }
    }
```

It's not the same to bind an `ObservableCollection` than declaring the items into the `ComboBox` control.

Comment: This is a horrible suggestion. Binding to a view model property of type `object` only because you don't want to use the right properties in XAML?